# Referenced Objects in List Change on Contents Change, but Not Setting to NULL

Tags: java

I have this code which adds some objects to an ArrayList. Then, from the List, in Step 1, I modify the contents of these objects -- and the backing objects themselves also change, which works. Then, in Step 2, from the List I set my objects to NULL. The list changes - I can see its elements are NULL, but the backing objects do **not** change. Why is that?

My expectation: a, b, c are set to NULL.

```
public class Test {

static class Student
{
    String name;
    int age;

    public Student(String name, int age) { this.name = name; this.age = age; };
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Student a = new Student("John", 20);
    Student b = new Student("Mary", 21);
    Student c = new Student("Bill", 22);

    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    students.add(a);
    students.add(b);
    students.add(c);

    // STEP 1: Changing contents from list: THIS WORKS - Referenced objs change (a, b, c)
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)           
        students.get(i).setName("NEW NAME");


    // STEP 2: Setting to null from list: DOES NOT WORK - Referenced objs do NOT change (a, b, c)
    for (int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++)
        students.set(i, null);


}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how references work. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: Did you read "Expectation" at the top? I need a,b,c to be NULL.

Comment: I am blind, sorry :-)

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12429953/1079354) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7034719/1079354) explain what's happening with your references.

Comment: Simply assign the arraylist to null. Why take so much pain.

Comment: @PritamBanerjee:  That would be conterproductive, most likely.  In the grand scheme of things, since this is the last action in `main`, there's really no reason to set these things to `null` unless there's more code that you're not sharing.

Answer (score 0):

array list simply holds the references to your objects. so when you set the reference to null it does not delete the backed object.
try reading this [article](http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm) about how data is referred to in java.

Comment: but then how would I set my backed objects to NULL? That's what I need to do.

Comment: @geneb. You have no choice but to do it one by one: `a = null; b = null; c = null;`.

Comment: all objects are only deleted when the garbage collector finds no more references to them. so if you set everything to null in your arraylist and then set a, b and c to null then your objects will be deleted. you can also try not to save a, b and c and just directly add them to arraylist. like students.add(new Student("John", 20));, now if you students.set(0, null); it will be completely removed